# Any suggestions for good Remote Desktop apps for connecting CentOS7 to Windows10?

Tags: centos, software-rec, rdp

Any suggestions for good RDP/VNX apps for connecting CentOS7 to Windows10?

I'm currently using TigerVNC from my CentOS machine and it's really slow connection... has anyone got any good RDP/VNC or anything that will remotely connect from CentOS to Windows that they would suggest using?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details? Like, which machine are you physically using and which is remote? These details matter.

Comment: @0xSheepdog Thanks for your reply, I'm running CentOS7 and want to remotely connect from that to my Windows 10 PC. I've got the rdp from my windows to the centos using xrdp, it just doesn't work the other way round! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Remmina` is a good vnc/rdp client.

Slow connections are usually not an indicator of a bad client.

Comment: Thanks - I assume 'sudo yum install Remmina' would do the trick?

Comment: Possibly, I don't usually memorise package names :)

Comment: The package name is “remmina” and is in EPEL, so you need to install the “epel-release” package first.  I also recommend “freerdp” which is part of CentOS, and is very flexible. I believe Remmina uses it for RDP connections.

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks

Comment: @pedro Thanks for your help